# PHP client side é viável?

Tags: php, aplicação-web, lado-do-cliente

Desenvolvo em PHP e, adoraria fazer tudo somente em PHP em questões de programação dinâmica, mas, sei que para fazer tudo que preciso voltado para "web" impossível seria sem uma linguagem *client side*.

Meu objetivo com a linguagem de programação dinâmica é somente voltada para sistemas *web based*, por isso PHP torna-se sempre a linguagem principal dos meus projetos com aproximadamente 80% do escopo.

Existe algo que possa tornar o PHP uma linguagem *client side*, alguma biblioteca ou algo do tipo? Caso não, existe alguma possibilidade disso acontecer ou uma linguagem server-side sempre server-side?

Obs.: Esta dúvida é em relação as inovações que eu não esperava na linguagem HTML, por exemplo, entendo que HTML é uma linguagem estática, mas, HTML5 hoje faz verificações dinâmicas (*client side*) em inputs. CSS uma linguagem estática para estilos, hoje CSS3 utiliza condições dinâmicas (*client side*) para que uma determinada classe seja carregada.

Se eu estive errado gentileza me corrigir.

Comment: Usa javascript para o client e para o server side :D. html5 é puro js.

Comment: Vixi js tomando conta do mundo, tô enrolado mesmo... xD

Comment: [paypal troca java por javascript](http://www.infoq.com/br/news/2013/12/paypal-java-javascript)

Comment: @rray não domino javascript, sem fugir do assunto, sei que PHP não faz tudo que javascript faz. A grosso modo, javascritpt atende à tudo que PHP faz?

Comment: Se bobiar o js faz  até mais.

Comment: Vocês não estão confundindo client com server ? JavaScript é um auxiliar para o html, que ele faz as requisições para o PHP quando necessário, tentar comparar os dois dessa maneira é errada ao meu ver.
Me fale uma situação que você utilize somente o JavaScript para executar uma query no banco.

Comment: @FelippeTadeu, nodejs é javascript.

Comment: @ThyagoThySofT Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: @FelippeTadeu dá uma olhada nestes dois links: http://mean.io http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/ só não pode chorar.

Comment: Se não me engano foi descontinuado... mas tem o projeto php-gtk, para criar aplicações desktop usando o php. Se quiser dê uma olhada.

Comment: Você só vai usar uma única linguagem em exercícios de programação.

Answer (score 8):

<strike>Se vai programar para web não tem como fugir de JS. Pode fugir de todas linguagens de programação, menos de JS</strike> Isto não é verdade mais, já dá para usar diversas outras linguagens no *browser*. O máximo que daria para evitar é só usar HTML5. Limitaria algumas ações e duvido que trataria benefícios. Aprenda o que tem que aprender para fazer o melhor possível para os usuários. Não se apegue à ferramentas.

Utilize a ferramenta certa para cada aplicação. Não existe ferramenta universal.

Ah, nem PHP, nem outras linguagens podem ser usadas em navegadores. Até daria para alguém fazer um conversor, mas o resultado seria tão ruim, teria que se adaptar tanto, que não vale o esforço.

Algumas pessoas usam PHP como cliente, mas não web. Os resultados também não são maravilhosos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: concordo com você, mas em partes rs. Talvez não tenha mencionado que os desenvolvimentos web que tratamos é somente "sistemas web-based", ou seja, acredito que se tornaria inviável uma maior parte das funções sendo executadas do lado cliente, uma vez que não pode-se comparar o desempenho de processamento da máquina cliente e máquina servidor. Para desenvolvimentos tipo, site e afins tudo bem, agora sistemas web com toda a lógica e algoritmos, acredito que necessariamente neste caso, PHP precisa prevalecer, também por segurança do fonte.

Comment: Primeiro, se você não fornece informações adequadas, não espere respostas adequadas. Mas acho que neste caso nem faz diferença. E agora você está presumindo coisas que podem não ser verdade. Não vejo relação em a máquina ser cliente ou servidor e sua performance. Tão pouco o que isto tem a ver com a pergunta. Me parece que você está apenas desabafando o que seria seu desejo. Não é uma questão de concordar ou não, eu respondi o que é a realidade. Qualquer coisa fora disto não cabe neste site.

Comment: É, as informações não foram adequadas mesmo e por este motivo editei a pergunta adicionando um adendo. No mais não entendi muito bem o que quis dizer mas acho que o lugar de errar é justamente aqui, onde podemos ter ajuda, sinalizações, e edições de perguntas, respostas e comentários para nos adequarmos e adquirirmos experiências para que cada vez mais possamos atingir os objetivos e expectativas do site. Só não posso errar com meu cliente..... xD

Comment: bigown, considerando a pergunta que coloquei um adendo, talvez eu possa estar errado, por isso disse *"acredito que se tornaria"*, só acredito, se eu estiver errado e puder me dê esta ajuda. Funções javascript não chegam no servidor, não é assim? (não conheço bem js) Sei que PHP executa do lado servidor e entrega pronto ao navegador do cliente, js não estaria processando as funções/scripts no navegador do cliente e consequentemente estaria usando o hardware do cliente?

Comment: Existem desenvolvedores que misturam PHP com HTML em um arquivo. Partindo então desse princípio, sempre é mais recomendável criar dois arquivos separados, um HTML e outro PHP, sendo que o JavaScript ou HTML disparem requisições para o PHP? Não seria aconselhável ou é um padrão ruim misturar PHP ou HTML em um arquivo somente?

Comment: @GiancarloAbelGiulian vai de gosto, eu prefiro separado na medida do possível.